# Problema con columnas de bootstrap ocupan espacio de las columnas inferiores

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Mi problema es al generar de manera dinámica columnas del tipo "col-md-4" pero si una se excede de contenido como se ve en la imagen hace que las columnas siguientes se brinquen ese espació.
[image]

Lo que busco es que respete el espacio del div de arriba y no se mueva a la derecha.
Edito: agrego la estructura de los div's dentro de cada uno es donde agrego el contenido.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="clearfix col-md-4">
    <!--contenido del div -->
    </div>
  <div class="clearfix col-md-4">
    <!--contenido del div -->
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix col-md-4">
    <!--contenido del div -->
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix col-md-4">
    <!--contenido del div -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Claro, el float funciona así, se colocan donde tiene hueco. Pon el código que tienes, no una imagen.

Comment: como bien te comenta @blonfu el float de las columnas hace eso, deberás añadir un `clear` después de la 3ª columna

Comment: @blonfu el código es un <div .row> y dentro se generan los <div .col-md-4> por cada encuesta a través de un ciclo y cuando termina se cierra el row;

Comment: Incluye el código html si la respuesta de abajo no ha solucionado tu problema, porque sino vamos a ciegas

Comment: @Cheshire ya edite la pregunta, intente agregar <div class='clearfix'></div> entre cada <div .col-md-4> y los mueve poniéndolos una fila cada uno.

Comment: deberías hacer un row por cada tres bloques, y si no poner un `clear:both` en el último, la clase clearfix no te va a solucionar eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a todos por su ayuda, la respuesta es usar el selector :nth-child

`@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .row > div:nth-child(2n+3) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .row > div:nth-child(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
  }

}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row > div:nth-child(4n+5) {
    clear: left;
  }

}`

aqui les dejo la explicación por si alguien llegara a tener el mismo problema https://stackoverflow.com/a/27053838/5224602

Answer (score 0):

Te encontrarás con ese problema cuando las columnas tengan diferente altura. Para solucionarlo con Bootstrap utiliza la clase clearfix con la clase auxiliar tipo visible-resolucion.

Añade justamente delante del div que te sale desordenado el siguiente código:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
```

Ese código te lo solucionará en esa resolución en cuestión aplicando un reseteo.

Puede ser que siempre se te vea bien pero al pasar a col-sm sea cuando se te vea mal y ocurra lo mismo, en ese caso tendrás que cambiarlo por

```
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias pero al ser generados dinamicamente no puedo ponerlo en el ultimo ademas a veces pueden ser mas de 4 encuestas o "div's".

Comment: Puedes hacerlo por medio de condicionales supongo, no??

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es usar otro `div` con la clase `row`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix col-md-4">
      <!--contenido del div -->
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix col-md-4">
      <!--contenido del div -->
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix col-md-4">
      <!--contenido del div -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix col-md-4">
      <!--contenido del div -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```